# Expand complex exponentials to trig functions in Sympy

Tags: python, sympy, simplify

I have the following sympy code:

```
W, k = symbols('W k', real=True)
expr = exp(W)*(exp(I*k) - exp(-I*k))
print(expr)
```

[image]

and I would like sympy to simplify it to:

```
exp*(W)(2*I*sin(k)
```

[image]

I have tried `expr.simplify()` and `expr.trigsimp()` but they don't substitute any trig functions. The only partial solution I was able to find is

```
expr.rewrite(cos).trigsimp()
```

but this also expands `exp(W)` to hyperbolic sine/cosine, which I don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, using

```
expr.rewrite(cos).simplify()
```

[image]

worked.

Answer (score 2):

```
expr.expand(complex = True).simplify()
```

should work.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While your code snippet may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how your code snippet works improves its long-term value.